# create customized GUI using GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I'm trying to create customized interface like the one displayed by daches:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-  -----------------------------------------------------------  -
-  -                                                         -  -
-  -----------------------------------------------------------  -
-                                                               -
-                           ----------                          -
-                           -        -                          -
-                           ----------                          -
-                                                               -
-  ----------  -----------------------------------  ----------  -
-  -        -  -                                 -  -        -  -
-  ----------  -----------------------------------  ----------  -
-                                       ----------  ----------  -
-                                       -        -  -        -  -
-                                       ----------  ----------  -
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I followed the example Here [GroupLayout Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/groupExample.html)

Here is the code i used:

```
GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
            .addComponent(msgLbl)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()

                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                        .addComponent(empty)
                        .addComponent(fldrLbl3)
                        .addComponent(empty))   
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)   
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(empty)
                            .addComponent(timerLabel)
                            .addComponent(empty))
                        .addComponent(fldr)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(empty)
                            .addComponent(empty)
                            .addComponent(strtButton)))

                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                        .addComponent(empty)
                        .addComponent(chFldrButton)
                        .addComponent(PstPndButton))            
        ));

    layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, empty, empty, empty, strtButton, PstPndButton);


    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(msgLbl)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                .addComponent(empty)
                .addComponent(empty)
                .addComponent(timerLabel)
                .addComponent(empty)
                .addComponent(empty))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                .addComponent(fldrLbl3)
                .addComponent(fldr)
                .addComponent(chFldrButton))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
                    .addComponent(empty)
                    .addComponent(empty)
                    .addComponent(empty)
                    .addComponent(strtButton)
                    .addComponent(PstPndButton))

        );
```

But it is not display correctly for some reasone. I think I'm missing something, can you help me??

//**********************************************************************//
What I was missing is the use of Alignment enum: LEADING, TRAILING, CENTER, and BASELINE.

It was more cleare when i followed: [How to Use GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html)

Just for futur users the correct way is:

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(fldrLbl3)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(CENTER)
                .addComponent(msgLbl)
                .addComponent(timerLabel))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(TRAILING )
                .addComponent(fldr)
                .addComponent(strtButton)) )
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
            .addComponent(chFldrButton)
            .addComponent(PstPndButton))
            );


    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(CENTER)
                .addComponent(msgLbl))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(CENTER)
                .addComponent(timerLabel))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                .addComponent(fldrLbl3)
                .addComponent(fldr)
                .addComponent(chFldrButton))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                .addComponent(strtButton)
                .addComponent(PstPndButton)
                )

        );
```

Comment: One can use `Nested Layout`s, in order to create this View. If that is acceptable, other than `GroupLayout`, then I can provide one example.

Comment: @nlcE cOw sure I just want to create the layout and i thought thisis the bestway.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this question, one more time, for the extra input that you have given, to your own POST. But I can only upvote once. It really feels good, when someone wants to learn somethingy new, without being eager to be spoon fed first. Really appreciate, the added effort you gave to your own post :-)

Comment: Thanks We all here to learn and support each other :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the output, using `Nested Layout`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NestedLayout {

    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private Random random;

    public NestedLayout () {
        random = new Random ();
    }

    private void displayGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Nested Layout Example" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ();
        contentPane.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder (
                                GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP) );
        contentPane.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 4, 1, GAP, GAP ) );

        contentPane.add ( getHeaderPanel () );
        contentPane.add ( getMiddlePanel () );
        contentPane.add ( getFooterPanel () );
        contentPane.add ( getPSPanel () );

        frame.setContentPane ( contentPane );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    private JPanel getHeaderPanel () {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setLayout ( new BorderLayout ( GAP, GAP) );
        panel.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder (
                                GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP) );
        panel.add ( getLabel ( "Header JLabel" ), BorderLayout.CENTER );

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel getMiddlePanel () {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setLayout ( new GridBagLayout () );
        panel.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder (
                                GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP) );
        panel.add ( getLabel ( "Middle JLabel" ) );

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel getFooterPanel () {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setLayout ( new BorderLayout ( GAP, GAP) );
        panel.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder (
                                GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP) );

        panel.add ( getLabel ( "Left JLabel" ), BorderLayout.LINE_START );
        panel.add ( getLabel ( "Center JLabel" ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
        panel.add ( getLabel ( "Right JLabel" ), BorderLayout.LINE_END );

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel getPSPanel () {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setLayout ( new FlowLayout ( FlowLayout.RIGHT, GAP, GAP) );
        panel.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder (
                                GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP) );

        panel.add ( getLabel ( "First JLabel" ) );
        panel.add ( getLabel ( "Second JLabel" ) );

        return panel;
    }

    private JLabel getLabel ( String text ) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel ( text, JLabel.CENTER );
        label.setOpaque ( true );
        label.setBackground ( getRandomColour () );
        return label;
    }

    private Color getRandomColour () {
        return new Color ( random.nextFloat (), random.nextFloat (),
                            random.nextFloat (), random.nextFloat () );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                new NestedLayout ().displayGUI ();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater ( runnable );
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: NESTED_LAYOUT]

Comment: @user2320492 If you feel this answers your question please upvote and/or accept the answer.  :-)